# html5 video // autoplay

Tags: html5-video, autoplay

I am showing a div width Text over the poster image while the video is loading and when the video is paused.

How can I detect the moment the video is fully loaded and autoplay starts? Because then, the div should be hidden.

Answer (score 1):

It you have defined autoplay then detect using the [play](https://devdocs.io/dom_events/play) event:

```
video.onplay = function() { /* remove overlay here */ };
```

alternatively use [canplay](https://devdocs.io/dom_events/canplay) or [canplaythrough](https://devdocs.io/dom_events/canplaythrough) when you want to manually trigger play.